# No results appearing to me when I debug the application on chrome

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

When I try to debug my application on chrome there are no results that appear to me, I don't know if this issue is from my device or code.

I have added SVG Image to my project but I don't know if this issue came because of it, SVG Worked without a problem but the main problem is nothing is appearing in chrome when I debug it, also when I tried to debug it many times it took me to system.chrome.dart page. [flutter error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvYGX.png)

This is the Error :

```
This RenderObject had the following child:
    text: TextSpan
Another exception was thrown: RuntimeError: unreachable
Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:348:12
Another exception was thrown: RuntimeError: unreachable
3
Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:1966:12
Another exception was thrown: RuntimeError: unreachable
```

These are the codes :

```
// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables, prefer_const_constructors, unused_import

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: FacebookApp(),
    );
  }
}

class FacebookApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const FacebookApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("facebook",
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.blueAccent,
                fontSize: 27,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700)),
        centerTitle: true,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.menu,
            color: Colors.blueAccent,
            size: 30,
          ),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.message,
                color: Colors.blueAccent,
                size: 30,
              ),
              onPressed: () {}),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.search,
              color: Colors.blueAccent,
              size: 30,
            ),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ],
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        elevation: 20,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to create a new project and change the editor code but still exists.